# How to share a website in FBSDKShareDialog in Graph API 2.9 for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I've been trying to implement a similar solution for sharing a website using `FBSDKShareDialog` for iOS (FB SDK). From July, 2017 my current implementation is deprecated:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = @"http://www.ironmaiden.com";
content.contentTitle = @"This is the best band ever"; 
content.imageURL = @"http://ironmaiden.com/media/images/book-of-souls-bg.png";     
FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
```

The closest solution to this is by using `FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject` and set up the meta tags:

```
 NSDictionary *properties = @{
                             @"og:type": @"website",
                             @"og:title": @"Up the Irons",
                             @"og:description": @"This is the best band ever",
                             @"og:image": @"http://ironmaiden.com/media/images/book-of-souls-bg.png",
                             @"og:url": @"http://www.ironmaiden.com"
                             };
 FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

 FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
 action.actionType = @"og.likes";
 [action setObject:object forKey:@"og:object"];

 FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
 content.action = action;
 content.previewPropertyName = @"og:object";

 FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
```

this works just fine except when I share it the action is displayed as: 
[See example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJN6E.png)

`Username likes an object on Iron Maiden Fan.` : How can I rename the `object` to a something different like `website` ?

I found in documentation:

`This action and associated object types are automatically added to the App Dashboard when you use the action for the first time.`

But that's not very helpful, clearly I'm missing some set up either in FB Dashboard or FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject declaration,  I appreciate any help

Comment: @the4kman Not duplicate, I've read that question several times, all ti do is to address to FB documentation, where actually can't find a proper implementation for this problem, I my description I've implemented a solution, but got stuck in the action name